# If ? found in redirect url, then change url

Tags: javascript, url, redirect

Please see this [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pb5Sg/)

I have got it developed for stackflow only..
Now i just have a little problem with it.

If the final url which will be redirected consist of `?` or `&`  in it, then instead of `addQueryString` ,    `addQueryString1`  should be used..
Can anyone help please.

Sorry Rohit and Tim. I thought it would be easier if you see the code directly there. But here is my code :

```
   // Plain Javascript

    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (var i = 0, max = links.length; i < max; i++) {
        var _href = links[i].href;
        var addQueryString = "?utm_source=tyroo&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=12june12_20percenteossoffer";
        var addQueryString1 = "&utm_source=tyroo&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=12june12_20percenteossoffer";

        if (_href.indexOf('gog.com') !== -1) {
            links[i].href = 'http://example.com/lnkurl=' + _href + encodeURIComponent(addQueryString);   
        }       
    }
​
```

It is a code for redirecting affiliate link found in the webpage via a affiliate url so that we earn commission from the links posted by users.
In my code, any link of gog.com will be redirected as   http://example.com/lnkurl=http://www.gog.com/%3Futm_source%3Dtyroo%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3D12june12_20percenteossoffer

Now i am asking you guyz, that if the link is for ex, gog.com/test?price=xyz
Now you see the link itself contain a ? and = in it. So the redirected url as per my script will become :   http://example.com/lnkurl=http://www.gog.com/test?price=xyz%3Futm_source%3Dtyroo%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3D12june12_20percenteossoffer

which won't work.
All i want to do is, if the url contains any ? or & or = in it, then it should use  addQueryString1  instead of  addQueryString   .. and also, if possible, the content in url starting from ? or & should also be encoded..

Please help if you guyz can.. thanks

Comment: First there is no URL in your post. Second, please post the code here, rather than posting URL.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your code should be posted here, not at jsfiddle. Your code appears to be JavaScript, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a javascript solution. if so you can follow this

```
if(url.indexOf("?") != -1)
{
  //? is present
} else    {
     //? is not present
}
```

Same for &